# Redirect routing html5Mode does not work angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Redirect routing html5Mode does not work angularjs

```
Just only setup this $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(false); into app.js
```

routing redirect issue hashPrefix does not working fine when i hit localhost:9000 it should takes me to localhost:9000/#!/login but it redirect me to localhost:9000/# why please suggest

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(false);

$routeProvider

    // Root URL.
    .when('/', {
      redirectTo: '/login',
      title: 'Login'
    })
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
      controller: 'login',
      title: 'Login'
    })
    .when('/term_of_services', {
      templateUrl: 'views/term_of_services.html',
      title: 'Privacy Policy'
    })
    .otherwise('/login');
```

Comment: Do you want to remove #! and keep your URLs clean?

Comment: I want to keep this #!, Initially it does not redirect to localhost:9000/#!/login later when i do copy and paste then it works

Comment: how about this: $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!') or conider to using html5Mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be somewhere you did wrong that causing this issue.

If you have just a case redirect success login then you can do this trick.

use path([path]);

This method is getter / setter.

Return path of current URL when called without any parameter.

Change path when called with parameter and return $location.

```
var url = $location.path();

if(url == '' || url == '/'){
      $location.path('login');
    }
```